# Xcode: table view header: snapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tableheader

I created a simple table view header in my UITableViewController:

```
UIView *tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height * 5 / 8)];

[tableHeaderView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor flatNavyBlueColorDark]];
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:tableHeaderView];
```

Now I want to creating a snapping/elastic behaviour so that when the user scrolls the table header to the point that when 50% of it is out of the main screen's frame, the rest of it automatically snaps so that the whole header scrolls out. As described by these images:

[Header is fully extended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x5uj.png)

[user scrolls to this point(halfway) and lets go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YveCG.png)

At this point, the header automatically snaps close.

Help?

Comment: You need to use the UIScrollViewDelegate methods to track the scrolling and then hide / show the header accordingly. I cannot write the solution for you, but that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a method in UIScrollViewDelegate called `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`, it gets called when the user stops scrolling, and lets you know where it's going to stop.

There you can check if `targetContentOffset.y` is in the range you want, and modify it, which will cause the scroll view to stop in a different location.